# Jquery UI Slider to navigate to Divs on page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I would like to create a single page navigation that uses jquery ui slider (unless something else might work better) which navigates to divs on the same page when moved, as well as moving itself when the user scrolls down the page.

Essentially it would be a timeline that scrolls to the relevant year selected.

Slider would resemble:

```
----------------◉---------------------
1984   1985   1986   1987   1988   etc
```

And page content would be:

```
<div id="1984">
Content
</div>

<div id="1985">
Content
</div>

<div id="1986">
Content
</div>

<div id="1987">
Content
</div>

<div id="1988">
Content
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm hoping something like this has been done before and I'm just not looking in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together an example of what I think you are trying to do. You can try this. It uses the jQuery slider slide event to scroll the page to the correct div

```
min = 1985
max = 1989

$("#slider").slider({
   min: min,
   max: max,
   step: 1,
   slide: function(event, ui){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+ui.value).offset().top
        }, 2000);
   }
});

$(window).scroll( function() {
});

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var height = $('body').height();
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop();

    sector = Math.round((1 / (height / offset)) * (max - min));
    $('#slider').slider('value', min + sector);
}, 250);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/apm39qx1/

Comment: This is exactly what I'm after! Is there a way to update the slider when the page scrolls?

Comment: I have now added some simple scrolling javascript to move the slider to the correct position.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I'm after. Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I've used a solution to a similar problem by using 
`$('div').show` and `.hide` along with `scrollTop`

You could modify my fiddle to suit your needs, this is my first Stack Overflow answer, hope it helps!

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="status"></div>
    <div id="statusb"></div>
    <div id="statusc"></div>
    <div id="statusd"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 1500px;
    padding: 100px;
}
#status {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:blue;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
    color:coral;
}
#statusb {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:red;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
}
#statusc {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:yellow;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
}
#statusd {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:orange;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 100px;
}
```

Juicy Bits:

```
$(document).scroll(function (e) {

    var squash = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (squash >= 250) {
        $('#status').show();
        $('#statusb').hide();
        $('#statusc').hide();
        $('#statusd').hide();

    }
    if (squash >= 500) {
        $('#status').hide();
        $('#statusb').show();
        $('#statusc').hide();
        $('#statusd').hide();

    }
    if (squash >= 750) {
        $('#status').hide();
        $('#statusb').hide();
        $('#statusc').show();
        $('#statusd').hide();

    }
    if (squash >= 1000) {
        $('#status').hide();
        $('#statusb').hide();
        $('#statusc').hide();
        $('#statusd').show();

    }

});
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/esco750/ruyagcoh/)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Link-only answers are discouraged here, because if your fiddle link goes bad, future readers of the answer won't be able to see it. Can you copy your code into the answer itself in addition to providing the fiddle link?

Answer (score 0):

It would probably something like the code above (self-explained):

```js
$(function() {
  showYear(1984);
  
  var slider = $('#slider').slider({
    min: 1984,
    max: 1988,
    range: "min",
    value: 1984,
    slide: function(e, item) {
      showYear(item.value);
    }
  });
  
  function showYear(year) {
    $('#years div').hide().parent().find('#' + year).show();
  }
});
```

```css
#slider {
  width: 80%
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="slider"></div>

<div id="years">
  <div id="1984">
    Content of 1984
  </div>

  <div id="1985">
    Content of 1985
  </div>

  <div id="1986">
    Content of 1986
  </div>

  <div id="1987">
    Content of 1987
  </div>

  <div id="1988">
    Content of 1988
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, will definitely come in useful for future ref. but for this I wanted to scroll down the page